# How can i load a different page at the click of a button in my frame?

Tags: php, html

I have a homepage(homepage.php) designed using frames. On various sections of the frame i have different pages being displayed, the Header page(header.php) and Footer page(footer.php). How can i load a new page(signin_up.php) leaving the homepage(homepage.php) when a user click on the 'Sign Out' button at the header(header.php) section?.

homepage.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>lect Group</title>
    <style>
.foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<frameset scrolling="no" rows="8%,84%,8%" framespacing="30" frameborder="yes" border="5" bordercolor="#999999">
  <frameset scrolling="no">
   <frame scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" class="foo" name="top" src="header.php"/> </frameset>
<frameset cols="22%,78%"  frameborder="yes"  >

   <frame class="foo" scorlling="no" noresize="noresize" name="accod" src="" />
   <frame scrolling="yes" src="" name="main" />

    </frameset><frameset>

<frame name="foot" src="footer.php" /> </frameset>  </frameset> 
   <noframes>
   </noframes>

</html>
```

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Head</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">lect Group</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form action="signin_up.php" class="navbar-form navbar-right">

           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign Out</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div> 

    </nav>
    </div></div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add the correct `TARGET` attribute to your `A` tag.

Comment: Well which 'TARGET' can i use because i want to leave the homepage to the sign in page(signin_up.php)? @Twisty

Comment: Your HTML is unclear as to which is the "homepage" frame. I would advise setting `ID` attributes for each of the frames such that you can direct links to them via `TARGET`. Two frames have no sources, so I can't determine what you're trying to load where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the sign out button to look like this

```
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
       <a class="btn btn-success" href="signin_up.php">Sign Out</a>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```